# How to query subcollections in AngularFire2/FireStore?

Tags: angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query subcollections in AngularFire2 with FireStore with no success.  Have searched but found no suitable solution.

```
ngOnInit() {
// this does work
this.africaCollection = this.afs.collection('Country', ref => ref
.where('code', '==', 'za'));
this.countriesAfrica = this.africaCollection.valueChanges();

// this does not work
this.townCollection = this.afs.collection('Country').doc('za')                         
.collection('Towns');
this.towns = this.townCollection.valueChanges();
{
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr *ngFor="let town of towns | async">
      <td>{{ town.name }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I am a newbie at this.

Comment: Can you use stackblitz.com to recreate the problem? I could help a lot more with an example (I'm the author of AngularFire)

Comment: Hi David - have difficulty using stackblitz but I have placed my attempt on github https://github.com/JacquesSchalkwyk/Firestore-Qry.  I hope this will help.  Currently my db has the default rule in where everybody can read and write.  the structure is Country-Towns-Listings

Comment: When I set the rules to :-service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /Country/{country}{
            allow read, write;
        }
    }
 }

Answer (score 1):

It may be related to your rules.

**Default rules**

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

More details about rules here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/secure-data#rules_dont_cascade

**Make sure you have items in that collection**

You can also add items to your collection by code to be sure it's correctly located. You'll then be able to look at your firebase console to see where it's been placed.

```
var town: Town = {
  name: "town name",
  region: "region name"
};
this.afs.collection('Country').doc('za').collection('Towns').add(town);
```

Comment: when I set the rules to service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /Country/{country}/Towns/{towns} {
            allow read, write;
        }
    }
 } my first qry runs but the second fails with permissions error

Comment: I've updated the rules example. Do you still get permission error with that version? if not, any other error?

Comment: Thank you.  Will try and post results.

Comment: Still reporting missing or insufficient permissions.  Will this help https://github.com/JacquesSchalkwyk/Firestore-Qry

Comment: Re-ran: getting no errors now, but still now towns.

Comment: Yes, you can wait up to 10 minutes for rules being applied. So if you don't get any error, what's the actual problem? Nothing being displayed?

Comment: Can you please update your post with explicit details about your data structure? And are you sure `/Country/za/Towns` is actually a collection and not an array on `/Country/za` document?

Comment: I tried your code at Firestore-Qry. If you add this `this.townCollection.ref.get().then((snapshot) => { console.log("Docs in collection", snapshot.docs); });` after you set `this.townCollection`, you'll see in the console that the collection is actually empty

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly to the fact that your collection was empty. Hope that will help you

Comment: I have dropped a screenshot of my db in my drive at this location. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B70Y1hIT-lVgajN4MjZQdTBaVDQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have found my mistake.  I was using a value of a field in country to get the town and not the id of the country. I copied the id of the country  into the code and it worked. Your answer led me to take a closer look.  Thank you so much for your patience. Today I will attempt to retrieve the id of the country before doing the town qry.  Once again thank you f3rland.  You have given this geriatric hope  again.